# How come the Russian cognate for the Czech word "čerstvý" (fresh) means entirely the opposite thing (stale)?

Tags: этимология, история-языка, other-languages, slavic

In Russian, **черствый хлеб** (chorstvy khleb) is stale bread.

And to my great surprise, I recently learned that in Czech, **čerstvý chléb** is precisely the opposite thing: fresh bread.

**My question is: What was the evolution of the meaning of черствый in the Russian language?**

Additional remarks about the evolution of the meaning of the same word in the Czech language are highly welcome, because I want to see how the Russian cognate for the Czech word "čerstvý" came to mean entirely the opposite thing. It stands to reason that if we trace back the evolution of the meaning of this word in Russian and Czech, the meanings will eventually converge. After all, Proto-Czechs and Proto-Russians spoke the same language, Proto-Slavic.

Comment: It is a pretty common phenomenon in related (but still very different!) languages. A common language splits and a common word starts evolving in different directions. Within a few centuries they happen to have drifted very far apart. (*it's not an inconsistency*)

Comment: And the "lists of funny words in Czech" are in abundance on the Internet, like [this one](http://lilinguist.com/blog/smeshnoj-cheshsko-russkij-slovar/), for example. (Many of them a full of fake words, so use with care).

Comment: It's not a question about Russian language - it's a question why Czech cognate for a Russian word means something different.

Comment: Languages do not owe each other a dime and calling the fact that some cognate has different meaning  in different languages "appalling inconsistency" it's a very strange thing to do.

Comment: @tum_ is it there yet? I think rules are one thing, respecting others time is another one. I can reopen this and close right after.

Comment: @tum_ anyway, just to let you know I've edited the question to make it on-topic (and reopened it subsequently). Have a good night though and sorry for causing you troubles.

Comment: @shabunc : >> *It's not a question about Russian language - it's a question why Czech cognate for a Russian word means something different*.<< I strongly disagree. My original version, the one I typed before you changed my question, was precisely about the Russian language. It was a question why a **Russian** cognate for a Czech word means exactly the opposite. The Czech language is more Slavic than the Russian language is, and hence has to be considered as the benchmark.

Comment: @shabunc : I have now edited the question to better reflect what I wanted to ask.

Comment: @Mitsuko than I’m really sorry it’s off-topic, in this form it’s not about Russian.

Comment: @shabunc : How is it not about Russian?! It is about the evolution of the meaning of a word in Russian and Czech. You even have a special tag for this: **other languages**. The tag is for questions that are partially about Russian and partially about other languages.

Comment: This can belong to Linguistics - once again, in it present form it’s not a question about Russian.

Comment: @shabunc : If my question is off-topic, how come you have the tag **other languages**?

Comment: @shabunc : If you want, I can re-formulate the question as follows: "What was the evolution of the meaning of this word in Russian? Additional remarks about the evolution of the meaning of this word in Czech are highly welcome, too." Would it be a satisfactory solution for you?

Comment: Also - I was under impression that you are getting some sort of linguistic-related education. Saying that language A is more Slavic (Germanic, Semitic) than language B is nonsense. Belonging to the same group means having the same ancestor.

Comment: It was edited to be on-topic however you’ve basically rolled it back and added lengthy explanation why you still insist. The very gist of the question however has not changed.

Comment: @shabunc : >> *Saying that language A is more Slavic (Germanic, Semitic) than language B is nonsense*. << By saying that Czech is more Slavic than Russian is I meant to say that Czech is closer to the ancestor (Proto-Slavic) than Russian is. I hope it makes sense for you now :)

Comment: @shabunc : Let me edit the question to address your concern, although I believe my question is on-topic as is.

Comment: @shabunc : Please have a look at the current version of the question. Is it fine now for you?

Comment: @Mitsuko thanks!

Comment: @shabunc :) well, I had a bit of a *déjà vu* a few minutes ago when the question was closed again in the middle of my work on the answer. Luckily, the text in the edit form gets preserved and I copied it to a file to make sure it's not lost... I suggest we remove the irrelevant comments, though.

Comment: @Mitsuko "By saying that Czech is more Slavic than Russian is I meant to say that Czech is closer to the ancestor (Proto-Slavic) than Russian is." - that's a very bold statement. I would like to hear your arguments in its support of this claim *(but unfortunately this is off-topic here)*.

Comment: @tum_ : >> *I would like to hear your arguments in its support of this claim* << Just open the revision history, and you will see my arguments :) https://russian.stackexchange.com/posts/20609/revisions

Comment: @Mitsuko ah, I see. Well, sorry but your arguments have nothing to do with linguistics as a science.

Comment: @tum_ : I could write scientific arguments, too. But it is off-topic for this question. I simply wrote some simple arguments appealing to the general public.

Comment: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/205305367

Comment: @Mitsuko Linguistics SE should be fine.

Comment: Akin, perhaps, to their being no Tass in Pravda, and no Pravda from Tass :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon "their" = "there"? :) Took me a while to decipher...

Comment: "Pozor" is another one. Attention in Czech and shame in Russian.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looking at the meanings of [cognates](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/%C4%8D%D1%8Crstv%D1%8A) of the Proto-Slavic **čь̑rstvъ**, one can notice the common meaning 'hard', 'strong', 'sharp'. I guess the Czechs and the Slovaks view fresh bread as 'hard on the outside', i.e. having a crispy crust, while Russian, Polish and others see it as 'hard on the inside', i.e. stale. It's just my guess.

There are other examples of this kind where cognates evolve to mean opposite things, e.g. Polish **uroda** 'beauty' and Russian **урод** 'ugly person'.

Comment: It's rather like this: Cz. strong > good > fresh; Ru. strong > hard > dried up, stale.

Comment: @YellowSky : Can you make an answer out of this, adding some details or references?

Comment: @Mitsuko - I'd rather not do that. Let that comment of mine rest here as a little supplement to the excellent answer by [Sergey Slepov](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/2104/sergey-slepov). Besides, after the [great answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/20613/1236) by [tum_](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/7386/tum) I have nothing to add.

Comment: The hard, crispy crust sounds really dubious.

Comment: Or French “blanc”, English “Black” - possibly from the white of fire (for French) and the black of the ashes (for English).

Comment: Same for "guest", "host", and "hostile" which derive from a root meaning "stranger" but made their way into English through different routes.

Comment: Yep, in Poland when we say bread is hard, we usually mean it is hard on the inside. For outside, we will rather say "chrupki", word better translated as crisp or crunchy.

Comment: @Tim Hah, and ashes themselves - there's a reason "ashen" is a white colour. Ashes are usually not very dark :)

Answer (score 15):

I decided to turn my comment into an answer and add some references, etc.

It is a very common phenomenon in related (but, nonetheless, different **!**) languages. A common language splits into branches and a word starts evolving in different directions. Over the centuries the meanings of the word in those 'branches' (which gradually develop into fully-fledged languages) may drift very far from both the original meaning and each other.
(**Note:** *this is in no way an inconsistency*)

Wiktionary gives the following etymology for ["чёрствый"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> Происходит от праслав. *čьrstvъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   др.-русск. чьрствъ «твердый; сухой, черствый; безупречный; ясный;
>   значительный», укр. черстви́й «черствый, сильный, свежий», болг.
>   чевръ́ст, чвръст «жесткий, крепкий, ловкий, бодрый», сербохорв.
>   чвр̑ст, чвр́ста «крепкий, жесткий, полный, мясистый», словенск.
>   čŕstǝv, čvrst «крепкий, ядреный, бодрый, свежий», чешск., словацк.
>   čerstvý «свежий, бодрый», польск. czerstwy «свежий, бодрый, крепкий,
>   черствый» (из *czarstwy, вероятно, под влиянием czerstwieć), в.-луж.
>   čerstwy «бодрый».
>   Праслав. *čьrstvъ неоднократно сравнивали с др.-инд.
>   kr̥tsnás «полный, окончательный» и лат. crassus «толстый, грубый». Это
>   сближение весьма недостоверно ввиду того факта, что лат. crassus
>   расценивается как экспрессивное образование, связь которого с лат.
>   crātis «плетение», готск. haúrds «дверь» и т. д. весьма сомнительна.
>   Более удачно сравнение с готск. hardus «жесткий, твердый», греч.
>   κρατύς «сильный», κρατερός «более сильный», κράτος «сила». Сравнивают
>   čьrstvъ и с др.-исл. herstr «резкий», лит. ker̃štas «гнев».
>   *Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.*

[Ю.В.Откупщиков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) covers this phenomenon in Chapters 6 ("Развитие значений слова") and 7 ("Семантические закономерности") of one of his excellent books [К истокам слова. Рассказы о науке этимологии](https://libking.ru/books/sci-/sci-linguistic/245928-22-yu-otkupshchikov-k-istokam-slova-rasskazy-o-nauke-etimologii.html#book) (*I highly recommend this book to all interested in etymology (as a branch of linguistics) and the comparative method specifically. It is meant for children mostly but is an interesting read for anyone and can be seen as "Etymology for Dummies", if you like*):

> **О свежем и чёрством хлебе**
>
> Как-то раз один чешский студент, учившийся в Москве и не очень хорошо
>   знавший русский язык, зашёл в булочную купить хлеба. Продавщица
>   любезно предупредила его, что хлеб, который он выбрал себе; —
>   чёрствый. Студент-чех поблагодарил продавщицу и сказал, что это как
>   раз то, что ему нужно. Но увы — оказалось, что покупатель и продавщица
>   не поняли друг друга. Дело в том, что чешское čerstvỷ chlẻb [чéрствы:
>   хле: б] означает совсем не черствый, а, наоборот, ‘свежий хлеб’.
>
> Такие недоразумения особенно часто встречаются в близкородственных
>   языках.
>
> Например, сербское слово зной значит ‘пот’, куча — ‘дом’, и́грати — ‘танцевать’, слово — ‘буква’, ки́снути — ‘мокнуть’, любити — ‘целовать’;
>   болгарское стая имеет значение ‘комната’, гора — ‘лес’, дума—‘слово’, неделя — ‘воскресенье’, стол — ‘стул’ и т. п.
>   Сербское слово домовина означает ‘родина’, а украинское домовина — ‘гроб’.
>    …

Unfortunately, the author does not go into the detailed analysis of this particular transformation (čerstvỷ/чёрствый). However, he gives another similar example later on that outlines the idea:

> **Как стая стала ‘комнатой’**
>
> Почему же слова, несомненно восходящие к одному и тому же общему
>   источнику, приобретают иногда даже в близкородственных языках
>   совершенно различное значение? Как это происходит?
>
> Возьмём в качестве примера русское слово стая и болгарское стая
>   ‘комната’. В древнерусском языке и в диалектах современного русского
>   языка словом стая обозначалось ‘стойло, хлев’. Этимология этого слова
>   достаточно прозрачна: стая представляет собой место, где стоит скот.
>
> Позднéе значение слова стая развивалось в двух различных направлениях:
>
> 1) ‘стойло’ → ‘стоянка скота’ → ‘стадо (домашних животных)’ → ‘стая’
>   (русский язык); 2) ‘стойло’ → ‘сарай’ → ‘помещение’ → ‘комната’
>   (болгарский язык).
>
> Подобного же рода семантические изменения произошли и в других
>   приведённых выше случаях. Но подробный их разбор занял бы слишком
>   много места и времени.

…

> Таких примеров можно привести немало из самых различных языков. Пути
>   развития противоположных значений в слове не всегда одинаковы. И не во
>   всех случаях эти пути могут быть прослежены с достаточной
>   определённостью.
>
> Сравнительно простой в этом отношении пример — развитие значений у
>   слова бесценный. Если предмет не имеет никакой ценности, если он
>   слишком дёшев для того, чтобы за него можно было назначить хоть
>   какую-то цену, его называли бесценным, то есть дешёвым. Это значение в
>   современном русском языке является устаревшим, но оно сохранилось,
>   например, в выражении купить за бесценок. Чешское слово bezcenny
>   [бэ:сцены:] также означает ‘ничего не стоящий’ и (в переносном смысле)
>   — ‘ничтожный’. В настоящее время мы обычно употребляем слово бесценный
>   в прямо противоположном значении: ‘дорогой’. Такое употребление слова
>   довольно легко объяснимо. Речь в данном случае идёт о столь дорогом
>   предмете, который мы не согласны уступить ни за какую цену, о
>   предмете, которому и цены нет. Так возникло у слова бесценный его
>   второе значение, ставшее основным в современном русском языке.

Basically, the whole chapter 6 is dedicated to this phenomenon, while chapter 7 is the continuation on this topic.

[Another link](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000014/st007.shtml) to the same book with arguably better formatting, images, and, I believe, slightly different content (the original edition?). *This link is provided by ['Общее языкознание'](http://genling.ru/)*.

*[For the fun of it](https://www.adme.ru/svoboda-kultura/veselyj-cheshsko-russkij-slovar-961610/amp/) (there is some new "food for thought" there as well, though.)*

Comment: Раз уж речь зашла о развитии значений слов, не могу не упомянуть замечательную книжку Чуковского "Живой как жизнь" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C

Comment: О, наконец-то узнал почему "стайка" так называется!

Answer (score 6):

The original meaning of the proto-Slavic etymon seems to have been "robust, sturdy".

It had later shifted its meaning to "hard" in Russian and to "good, wholesome" in Czech.

Answer (score 3):

*Иногда одно и то же слово, встречаясь в двух языках, имеет в них значение не то что «несходное», а скорее прямо противоположное. Вот пример: мы говорим «черствый» о хлебе, который уже остыл и засох; «теплый», мягкий хлеб у нас противопоставляется холодному, «черствому». А у чехов слово «черстви» означает как раз наоборот: «свежий», «прохладный». Каким же образом так разошлись значения этого слова? Подумайте сами: в обоих языках есть и общий оттенок значения: «холодный», «остывший». Остывший хлеб – черствый хлеб. Человек, в груди которого «остыли чувства», – черствый, холодной души человек. Это у нас, в русском языке. А чехи пошли по другой линии. У них «черстви витр» – «прохладный», то есть свежий, ветер. Одно и то же слово у двух народов имеет противоположные, но тесно связанные между собою значения.*

From Лев Успенский. Слово о словах. Лениздат, 1962г.

Comment: I would choose this as the accepted answer as it's straight to the point. Although @turn_'s answer is more comprehensive and deep.

Answer (score -3):

Not knowing anything about Russian or Czech, however still want to give my two cents about it. Perhaps the derived opposite meaning in Russian came to be through irony. Russians saying a lot to each other "Well this bread is really 'fresh'". Overtime the irony became lost.

Comment: While it's a nice theory but it still have to be backed by some evidence.

Comment: This theory is as good as mine (which got 29 upvotes currently). StackExchange works in mysterious ways.